# Word Unscrambler Complexity Class

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm not that well experienced in the field of complexity classes and related concepts. But, would the task of outputting whether or not a given scrambled word is a real english word be a P or NP problem? (if that even makes sense) All programs that I've seen take the input and generate all permutations of the word, then compare all permutations to every word in the dictionary. What if there was another algorithm that took a different, more efficient approach? Would that change the problem's class complexity? Sorry if I'm using the terminolgy incorrectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to generate all permutations. Just count the number of times each letter appears in the word and compare the counts,
or sort the letters of each word then compare them. These operations are all polynomial so in P.

Comment: \*Hitting head on table for not thinking of this\*

Answer (score 1):

Generating permutations of a word with *k* necessarily has exponential complexity, because there are *k!* permutations, and the algorithm needs to create them all. However, the lookup part can be made more efficient with the use of a datastructure which is called a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which allows a lookup to be performed in near-constant time.

Comment: So what class in the complexity classes would this problem fall under?

Comment: Based on this information, could you express the algorithm's runtime complexity with the _O_ or _Theta_ notation?

Comment: In big O notation, I imagine it would be O(k!) because that's the expression that grows that largest as k approaches infinity

Comment: Yes, but you also need to take into account the time that is needed to build the hash table initially, so it's _O(k! + n)_, where _n_ is the number of words in the dictionary. Whether this is exponential or not depends on whether you consider _k_ a constant or not - for most real languages, there's a limit to how long words are, but from a theoretical standpoint, it's probably best to consider it a variable anyway (and in practice, words can be so long that _k!_ is prohibitively big, especially in Norwegian, where e.g. _sannsynlighetsmaksimeringsestimator_ is a valid word).

Comment: ...so since _k_ describes the size of (a part of) your input, and the complexity contains a term that is exponential in _k_, and this is a decision problem in _P_, the problem is also in _NP_.

Comment: _fgb_ presents a much better algorithm; please use his answer.

Comment: when measuring algorithms in big O notation, you only take the expression that grows the largest as the input approaches infinity, but thank you for the answer, I was wondering whether it fell under P or NP

Answer (score 1):

The number of English words is bounded, and so obviously the possible length of any English word is bounded, so technically your problem is solvable in constant time (although the constant would be large). If you rephrase your question as say, you are given a dictionary of arbitrarily large length over an alphabet, and then for a query word you want to determine the answer, then things become more interesting. Then the answer given by @fbg is probably your best way to go;  hash the tuples of number of occurrences of each letter (say, taking the alphabet in some sorted order), for each word in your dictionary, and then if you are given a scrambled word and do the same hash, you can tell very quickly whether your query scrambled word can be "unscrambled" to give a solution, otherwise no solution in your dictionary exists.